# how to slove XML Parsing error inside file

Tags: python, ubuntu, github, gem5

I am trying to create the McPAT output and corresponding .csv file in the gem5_outputfile directory, it is explained in this tutorial

https://github.com/Hardik44/Gem5toMcPat_parser.

If I put this below command in ubuntu terminal in Gem5toMcPat_parser directory it works fine but when I go to gem5_outputfile I find the below error message inside config file.

```
./auto.sh /home/william/gem5/m5out  /home/william/gem5/Gem5toMcPat_parser-master   /home/william/gem5/mcpat
```

the error

```
McPAT (version 1.3 of Feb 2015) is computing the target processor...
XML Parsing error inside file '/home/william/Gem5toMcPat_parser-master/config.xml'.
Error: File not found
At line 0, column 0.
```

the output should be saved in gem5_outputfile but when I go to gem5_outputfile the .csv file is empty and the config file shows me the above error message.
How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Does the config.xml file exist?

Comment: I'm also curious now, why are there so many McPAT questions recently? Is there a course going on? :-)

Comment: No, there is no config.xml, only config.json